# Conditionally create multiple rows from a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataset I've got is something like this:

```
Person 1, Person 1 Information, Person 2, Person 2 Information, Other Information
       a,                    b,        c,                    d,                 e
       f,                    g,      NaN,                  NaN,                 h
```

Where as above, some entries have a Person 2 and information concerning Person 2 and the others have only stuff for Person 1.

I'd like to split it into multiple rows when there is information on Person 2:

```
Person, Person Information, Other Information
     a,                  b,                 e
     c,                  d,                 e
     f,                  g,                 h
```

So in the case of the first row, it has been split into two rows with the `Other Information` on both, and the second row has just had the `NaN` data removed.

I've looked at iterating over the rows or combining the data into lists and then exploding the row but I don't know if pandas already has some tools to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long):

```py
import re

df = df.rename(
    columns=lambda x: re.sub("^Person (\d+) Information$", r"Person Information\1", x)
)

df = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        df, stubnames=["Person ", "Person Information"], i=["Other Information"], j="id"
    )
    .dropna()
    .reset_index()
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Other Information  id Person  Person Information
0                 e   1       a                  b
1                 h   1       f                  g
2                 e   2       c                  d
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
data = {
    'Person 1': ['a', 'f'],
    'Person 1 Information': ['b', 'g'],
    'Person 2': ['c', pd.NA],
    'Person 2 Information': ['d', pd.NA],
    'Other Information': ['e', 'h']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df1 = df[["Person 1", "Person 1 Information", "Other Information"]].copy()
df2 = df[["Person 2", "Person 2 Information", "Other Information"]].copy()
df1.rename(columns={"Person 1": "Person", "Person 1 Information": "Person Information"}, inplace=True)
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={"Person 2": "Person", "Person 2 Information": "Person Information"}, inplace=True)
df_new = pd.concat((df1, df2))
```

Answer (score 0):

here would be my try:
first make a sample dataframe:

```
dfw = pd.DataFrame([list('abcde'),
    ['f','g',float('nan'),float('nan'),'h']],
    columns=['Code_Person 1', 'Information_Person 1', 'Code_Person 2',  'Information_Person 2', 'Other Information'])
```

then make along format by:

```
person1df=dfw.iloc[:,[0,1,4]]
person1df.columns=["Person", "Person Information", "Other Information"]
person2df=dfw.iloc[:,[2,3,4]] 
person2df.columns=["Person", "Person Information", "Other Information"]
# Combine vertically
df_long=pd.concat([person1df, person2df],    
                      ignore_index = True,
                      sort = False).dropna(inplace=True)
```